# How to derive the coumn from a list of lists in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (`df`) and a list of lists (`mylist`) as follows.

```
node, item1, item2
n1, 25, 32
n2, 28, 31
n3, 33, 35

mylist = [['n5', 32], ['n2', 18], ['n1', 12]]
```

I want to add a new column to my `df` with the values of `mylist` as follows.

```
node, item1, item2, item3
n1, 25, 32, 12
n2, 28, 31, 18
n3, 33, 35, 0
```

Note that if the node is not in `mylist` the value is zero.

I was able to check if the value is `mylist` and if not make the value zero. However, I am thinking if there is a more straightforward way of doing this in pandas.

```
mylist_nodes = []
for item in mylist:
    mylist_nodes.append(item[0])
#check if the node is in mylist
df["item3"] = df_features["node"].isin(mylist_nodes).astype(int)
```

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your list to a dataframe, and then use merge.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'node': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'],
  'item1': [25,28,33],
  'item2': [32,31,35]
})
mylist = [['n5', 32], ['n2', 18], ['n1', 12]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mylsit, columns=['node', 'item3'])
final = df.merge(df2, how='left', on='node').fillna(0)

# final outputs:

  node  item1  item2  item3
0   n1     25     32   12.0
1   n2     28     31   18.0
2   n3     33     35    0.0
```

If the resulting dataframe needs `item3` to be an integer, you can then cast it as such. It gets upcast to a float, on my installed pandas version (0.25.2) because integers do not support nulls, which I believe has been changed in the next version of pandas.

casting can be done as below:

```
final['item3'] = final.item3.astype('int8')
```